# Using a map to set parameters for a rest call using RestTemplate

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-restcontroller

I am currently using a piece of code to set parameters and I do a REST call to a  URL using restTemplate, it works fine:

```
MultiValueMap<String, String> map = new LinkedMultiValueMap<String, String>();
map.add("grant_type", grantType);
map.add("client_id", clientId);
map.add("client_secret", clientSecret);
HttpEntity<?> entity = new HttpEntity<Object>(map);
restTemplate.exchange("myurl", HttpMethod.POST, entity, Void.class);
```

But if I am using a `LinkedMultiValueMap` it's because I looked on the web ;)

And if I replace it by a `HashMap`, it works as well, so can anyone tell me the advantage of using a `LinkedMultiValueMap` ?

Code with `HashMap`:

```
Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
map.put("grant_type", grantType);
map.put("client_id", clientId);
map.put("client_secret", clientSecret);
HttpEntity<?> entity = new HttpEntity<Object>(map);
restTemplate.exchange("myurl", HttpMethod.POST, entity, Void.class);
```

I can see we can preserve the order of the parameters in the `LinkedMultiValueMap`, but it does not matter in my project... And so if orders matters I still could use a `LinkedHashMap`

EDIT:

It looks like I need the MultiValueMap if I use APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED and HashMap, this code throw an exception :

```
Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
map.add("grant_type", grantType);
map.add("client_id", clientId);
map.add("client_secret", clientSecret);
HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
headers.setAccept(Arrays.asList(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));
headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED);
HttpEntity<?> entity = new HttpEntity<Object>(map, headers);
restTemplate.exchange("myurl", HttpMethod.POST, entity, Void.class);
```

Exception:

```
org.springframework.web.client.RestClientException: Could not write request: no suitable HttpMessageConverter found for request type [java.util.HashMap] and content type [application/x-www-form-urlencoded]
        at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate$HttpEntityRequestCallback.doWithRequest(RestTemplate.java:784)
        at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:567)
        at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:530)
        at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.exchange(RestTemplate.java:448)
        at uk.co.wowcher.marketplace.commons.rest.RestTemplateUtils.getForEntity(RestTemplateUtils.java:54)
        at uk.co.wowcher.marketplace.submission.service.ParameterService.getProductParameterVOs(ParameterService.java:38)
        at uk.co.wowcher.marketplace.submission.service.ParameterService$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$3f87231d.invoke(<generated>)
        at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:717)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
        at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.MethodInvocationProceedingJoinPoint.proceed(MethodInvocationProceedingJoinPoint.java:85)
        at uk.co.wowcher.marketplace.submission.logging.MarketplaceLogger.logMethodCalls(MarketplaceLogger.java:27)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor72.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
        at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AbstractAspectJAdvice.invokeAdviceMethodWithGivenArgs(AbstractAspectJAdvice.java:621)
        at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AbstractAspectJAdvice.invokeAdviceMethod(AbstractAspectJAdvice.java:610)
        at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJAroundAdvice.invoke(AspectJAroundAdvice.java:68)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
        at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:653)
        at uk.co.xxx.marketplace.submission.service.ParameterService$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$a52b80b.getProductParameterVOs(<generated>)
        at uk.co.xxx.marketplace.submission.service.SubmissionService.getAgreementData(SubmissionService.java:449)
       at uk.co.xxx.marketplace.submission.service.SubmissionService$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$92bbe798.invoke(<generated>)
        at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:717)
```

So, it looks like that setting some parameters with a HashMap is not a good idea at all...
So I removed the accepted answer for now, waiting more explanation on this point...
And I have the suitable converter (`converters.add(new FormHttpMessageConverter());`), I mean if I use a MultiValueMap I don't have the exception, so the HashMap is the problem!

Answer (score 5):

The only real advantage of using a `LinkedMultiValueMap` over other `Map` implementations is that it can store multiple values.

This is useful if you need to pass multiple values for the same key (for instance, if you need to pass a set of form checkbox values).

See the JavaDoc [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/util/MultiValueMap.html).

In your case, since you only have one value per key, you should be able to safely use a `HashMap`.

Answer (score 0):

`MultiValueMap` is used to store more than one value for a single KEY(`Map(key:ArrayOfValues[])`) while `LinkedMultiValueMap` does the same thing but with insertion order maintained. In your case, `HashMap` is enough because `LinkedMultiValueMap` performance will be slower than `HashMap` and `HashMap` is not required for your scenario.