# WAN Replication Synchronizing Target Cluster in Hazelcast through Rest call with Java client

Tags: java, hazelcast

I am trying to sync the data to  target cluster by rest call  in java ,with below  url 
https://hostname:port/hazelcast/rest/mancenter/wan/sync/map?clustername&groupname&mapname
In host name we have cluster FQDN we are using that with respective keystore but getting internal server error 500 in java .But through Curl command  Iam able to sync the data.But I need to implement as service
Please help me.

Comment: It depends how you call the REST call in Java. Can you please share the implementation details and log output?

Comment: I am using spring boot  rest template

Comment: HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();  headers .setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);URI uri = new URI(https://hostname:port/hazelcast/rest/mancenter/wan/sync/map?clustername&groupname&mapname); HttpEntity<JsonNode> entity = new HttpEntity<JsonNode>(headers); restTemplate.excahnge(uri,HttpMethod.POST,entity,JsonNode.class) @AlparslanAvci

Comment: org.springframework.web.client.HttpServerErrorException: 500 Internal Server Error.

Comment: Iam trying from last  two days ,I didnt get any other error other than 500 but when I change any thing in url it is giving 400,or if I change any host name,then it shows  unknown hostname.is there any details you need

Comment: Can you please try to send with content type `APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED ` instead of `APPLICATION_JSON` as in the example here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38388168/3327350?

Comment: Hi I am able to do sync  operation through rest call between two clusters .Previously   I used data  as JsonNode  in HttpEntity,But I need to pass data as String to post .I changes that one and I able to  do sync through rest call in java client

Comment: Thank you so much for your response @AlparslanAvci.I have one doubt .when we are doing the sync operation we want to lock our  hazelcast map operations .Is there any way to do in hazelcast.@AlparslanAvci