# POST request with form data using Spring RestTemplate

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc

I have to make a HTTP POST request with form data to an external API. Currently, I am invoking the API using the below curl command

```
curl https://books.zoho.com/api/v3/contacts?organization_id=10234695
-X POST
-H "Authorization: Zoho-oauthtoken 216793f385b9dd6e125f"
-H "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8"
-F 'JSONString="{
    "contact_name": "Bowman and Co",
    "company_name": "Bowman and Co",
    "website": "www.bowmanfurniture.com",
    "contact_type": "customer"
    }
```

I have implemented `ClientHttpRequestInterceptor` interface and registered the interceptor with the `RestTemplate`. I am not sure, how to post the HTTP request with form data. Kindly let me know, how to submit the form data or point me to any reference.

Inside my Controller class:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/v1/contacts")
public class ContactController {

    @Autowired
    private RestTemplate restTemplate;

    @PostMapping("/")

    public Invoice createContact(@RequestBody Contact contact){
        //TODO
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Kindly show us the code for the reciving API so we know how to tailor the request

Comment: @ThomasAndolf Updated the controller code. The controller gets the request body and then makes the POST request.

Comment: `return restTemplate.postForObject("externalApiUrl", contact, Invoice.class);` will work. Please try it.

Comment: @SudhirOjha But the object is of type formdata.

Comment: [How to POST form data with Spring RestTemplate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38372422/how-to-post-form-data-with-spring-resttemplate)

Answer (score 0):

You could use a rest template to make a post request with form data.

```
HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED);
MultiValueMap<String, String> map= new LinkedMultiValueMap<String, String>();
map.add("data", "data");

HttpEntity<MultiValueMap<String, String>> request = new HttpEntity<MultiValueMap<String, String>>(map, headers);

ResponseEntity<String> response = restTemplate.postForEntity( url, request , String.class );
```

Spring will automatically take care of the message converters used in this case.(The message converter used will be **FormHttpMessageConverter**).
Read [Doc](https://www.baeldung.com/rest-template)